# Is an object's color/shine/texture dependent on its electrons only? If electrons are same then why are there so many different colors?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons, atomic-physics

when we look at an object be it a metal or a non-metal are we looking at its electrons only, so then if all electrons are same then why do different chemicals or elements or objects have different color?
So basically are we detecting the energy emitted by the electrons only?

Comment: An equivalent question would be: Why materials have so different properties when all matter is made of protons and electrons?

Comment: Re-tagged as best I could. We don't have a tag that fits well for general, unionized gasses and I didn't think [magnetohydrodynamics] would add much.

Comment: Because the color comes from photons with different frequencies going into your eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The colors depend on the frequency of light. Let me explain. In atoms, there are various **discrete** [energy levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level) that electrons can occupy.

A photon that has energy (which remember depends of its frequency) which matches *exactly* the difference between the electron and the next excited state, will get absorbed by that electron and get excited to the next energy level. But that energy level is not stable, and in the order of usually nanoseconds it will decay back to the ground state by emitting a photon to get rid of that extra energy it has. This gives rise to color.

Now in real life, the structure we see involves molecules, which have a lot of energy levels. Those energy levels are still discrete, but they are so close to each other that they can be assumed to be continuous. This provides for a lot of possibilities for electrons to jump to lots of different energy levels hence giving rise to photons with different frequency/color.

There is also reflection methods etc which are summarised [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color#Physics_of_color)

Answer (score 2):

Well, we are not only looking at the electrons of an object when we look at it. 
What I understood your basic question to be is why we see different objects having different color. Well the reason for that is because different materials are able to reflect only certain frequencies of light.

The reason for this is a little more complex. Color in itself is not a natural idea, it is instead a man-made idea. That is why different animals experience the same frequency of light as different 'colors'. When light hits a material, it interacts with the atoms that the material contains. Depending upon the structure of the atom, positioning of the electrons, etc. the interaction is different for different atoms. As you have stated, the electrons are the same in all atoms, however, their positioning within the atom, attraction towards the nucleus, etc. these factors are not the same. Thus, they react differently to being hit by photons.

As an electron is hit by a photon, it jumps into a higher energy shell a moment, gaining energy from the photon. After some while, it drops back down to its original shell, releasing energy in the form of light. This is the light that we perceive as the color of the object.

The color of an object doesn't depend on the electron, rather the placement of the electron and the atomic structure of the atom it is in.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: so it does depend on the electron, and what we see are electrons.

Comment: Not exactly. We do not see the electrons, rather we see the emission of energy by them. They emit energy in the form of electromagnetic radiation, which is what our eyes pick up. Only a certain wavelength/frequency is emitted, thus we only see a specific color.